# Segment Sum Notation

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, numerical-linear-algebra

What is the correct notation to explicitly indicate a sparse matrix-vector contraction (segment sum)?

The following equation gives the essence of the operation

$$
   y_i
 =
   \sum_{j \ \in \ C_i} c_{i,j} x_{j}
$$

where $C_i = \{ j : c_{i,j} \neq 0  \}$. However, data structures such as CSR typically store the set $C = \{i, j : c_{i,j} \neq 0 \}$, but I don't know how to use this set to simultaneously define the bounds of the summation and the assignment index of $y$.

Comment: It seems that you can recover $C_i$ from $C$ by observing that $C_i=\{(k,j)\in C\mid k=i\}$. Although, I'm not sure I entirely understand the question.

Comment: The question is how to explicitly denote that a contraction is sparse (only consider nontrivial elements). My attempt was merely to help point out the sparsity (using the set output from something such as [scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html)). The computer operation is a segement sum ([numpy.add.at](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html))